# IndexOutOfBoundException in my Java ArrayList program

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception

The following program is supposed to ask user to enter integers, store them in an ArrayList, ask the order(i.e whether they want highest number among them, second highest, third highest, and so on) and display it:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Order
{
    public static int highestByOrder(int n, ArrayList<Integer> list)
    {
        int  nth_highest=0;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            nth_highest=0;
            int index=0;
            for (int el:list)
            {           
                if (el>nth_highest)
                {
                    nth_highest=el;
                    index++;
                }
            }

            if (n==1)
                break;
            else
                list.remove(index);
        }
        return nth_highest;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("How many elements do you want to enter? ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the elements: ");
        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            list.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the order: ");
        int order=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The highest element by order " + order + " is " 
        +  highestByOrder(order, list));
    }
}
```

I get 'IndexOutOfBoundsException' on running it. I'm unable to find anything wrong in my program. Please help!

This is the complete error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source) 
at Order.highestByOrder(Order.java:25) at Order.main(Order.java:43)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide the full error including any traceback, Thank you!

Comment: This is the full error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(Unknown Source)
   at Order.highestByOrder(Order.java:25)
   at Order.main(Order.java:43)

Comment: Please can you use the edit tool and add this to the body of your question.

Comment: Yes, I included the complete error in the question.

Comment: You have now, yes

Answer (score 0):

Cant add a comment so posting the comment as answer

I tried your program and it's working for me

How many elements do you want to enter? 
4
Enter the elements: 
7
2
9
3
Enter the order: 
2
The highest element by order 2 is 7

can you give me what values are you trying??/